# Microsoft Common Data Services - How to disable the service

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, power-automate, common-data-service

I went to my company's Power Apps Admin centre and there was a button saying 'Create my database'

In the attempts of creating a Microsoft Automate business process, I clicked this button and it asked what currency I want to use in the database and what language. I chose accordingly and like a real idiot, clicked 'Create my database' button again without reading anything.

Now I am freaking out as I don't know if this is going to cost my workplace. Did I create an empty database? Or a data server? I don't know how to undo/ delete. disable what I did.

The questions are:

1. Is this going to cost our company?
2. If so, how do I undo this/ disable the CDS?

There is also a link saying 'You can manage these settings in the Dynamics 365 Administration Center.'

I clicked this link and I will attach what I see when I click them. Seems like I created something today and I don't even know what I created.

Please help me to understand what I did and the financial impact of it.

Thank you in advance! 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I see screenshots, I believe you created D365 Instance with out of box entities. You can delete this env from your first screen or you can visit admin.powerapps.com and choose your instance and delete it.

Comment: did it helped? could you please let me know